# Is it possible to combine many MYSQL statement into one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a beginner in PHP and MySQL and I'm still in learning process. 
Is it possible to combine many MySQL statement into one query?
This is because I want to display every new output into new row in a table.
The coding below is not the right way to display the output like what I want.

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Staff Name</th>
  <th>Staff No.</th>
  <th>Grade</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Department</th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <?php
 $query="select staffName, staffNo from tblstaff";  
 $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());  
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 ?>
  <td><?php echo $row['staffName']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['staffNo']; ?></td> 
 <?php
 }
 ?> 
 <?php
 $query="select grade, gradePosition, gradeDepartment from tblgrade";  
 $result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error()); 
 while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 ?>
  <td><?php echo $row['grade']; ?></td> 
  <td><?php echo $row['gradePosition']; ?></td> 
  <td><?php echo $row['gradeDepartment']; ?></td> 
 <?php
 }
 ?> 
</tr>
</table>
```

The result for the above code is all the staff name and staff no in database table out first and then follow by all grade, position and department in a database table displayed in a row of the table. The output is not sequence accordingly like I want. Can anyone help me to solve my problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are using 2 tables, is there any relation between these two ? if so you can join them first then you can create table row and cells

Comment: There is no relation between this two tables. But relationship between table staff and table grade is one to many which is FK for table staff is id from table grade. Is it possible to use join between this two table?

Comment: Can you show the table structure for both?

Comment: If there is some relation between the tables you can use joins. That will be better solution.

Comment: *There is no relation between this two tables. But relationship between table staff and table grade* - This statement makes no sense. Either there is a relationship, or there isn't! This is SQL. It is the Query that establishes the Structure!

Answer (score 0):

Two options,
INNER and LEFT joins can join two tables togeather.

INNER JOIN will only display results if data for the records exists in both table,
IE, only staff with position and department.

LEFT JOIN will get all staff, and fill in the other table information if it is available.

```
SELECT staffName, s.staffNumber, grade, gradePosition, gradeDepartment 
FROM tblstaff s
(INNER/OR/LEFT) JOIN tblgrade g on s.staffNumber = g.staffNumber
```

This solution requires a relation between the two tables, which they should have if they are related.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. Use mysqli_multi_query() function.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for downvote. Isn't this function used for multiple queries?